# Selecting each item except last element of a nested div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

```
<div class="main">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
</div>
```

I need to append a comma to every element inside span except the last. Here is the selector i am using

```
$(".main span :not(:last)").append(', ');
```

But its appending to every element except the very last item that is 7. How can i select theme separately? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is adding all elements matched to the same collection, even though they are not in the same container. As you said, you'll need to target [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) `div` individually and then search for the `span` inside.

```js
$('.main').each(function() {
  $(this).children('span:not(:last)').append(', ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you can do it like so:

```
 $(".main").each(function() {
   $(this).find("span:not(:last)").append(', ');
 })
```